# Replace the floor tile with a different one in an iPad application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, image-processing

I'm working on an iPad application and I have some room photos (static ones and not taken using camera) and a set of room and wall tiles. When the user taps on a particular wall tile, that tile should replace the current wall tile and the same goes with floor tiles too.

I've the liberty to decide on the format of the room photos and the tiles.

This is a 2D application and there is no need to rotate or change the camera angles. The room picture might look something like this http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-21408846-modern-living-room-interior.php?st=921a601

Have been pondering on this problem for a few days now and thought will raise it here in SO. What would be the best approach here ?

Comment: the tile which you are going to change is uiimage,right?

Comment: Like I said, I have the liberty to chose whether it's an image or a texture. I was thinking more like using a solid color in areas where I need to replace the tiles and then it becomes alot easier. wdyt ?